# SAP Fiori Elements Navigation Links Not Generated

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm developing an application using SAP's Fiori Elements and an oData V4 service. The application is a standard List Report and Object Page. I've made several of these applications before, and always the link between the List Report and the Object page is automatically generated. However, in this case only the link is not generated. When I click a row on the List Report Page, no navigation to the Object Page is generated. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I suspect the issue could be related to the oData service itself, but I can't find any information about where in an oData service a Fiori Elements page might derive this link. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is an image of the screen output:
[screen ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgVnS.png)

Below is the relevant parts of my manifest:

```
{
  "_version": "1.8.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "id": "sales",
    "type": "application",
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "dataSources": {
      "ProjectService": {
        "uri": "/api/project/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
          "odataVersion": "4.0"
        }
      }
    },
    "-sourceTemplate": {
      "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
      "-id": "ui5template.smartTemplate",
      "-version": "1.40.12"
    }
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "dependencies": {
      "libs": {
        "sap.fe.templates": {}
      }
    },
    "models": {
      "i18n": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
        "uri": "i18n/i18n.properties"
      },
      "": {
        "dataSource": "ProjectService",
        "settings": {
          "synchronizationMode": "None",
          "operationMode": "Server",
          "autoExpandSelect": true,
          "earlyRequests": true,
          "groupProperties": {
            "default": {
              "submit": "Auto"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "routing": {
      "routes": [
        {
          "pattern": ":?query:",
          "name": "SalesList",
          "target": "SalesList"
        },
        {
          "pattern": "SalesOrders({key}):?query:",
          "name": "SalesDetails",
          "target": "SalesDetails"
        }
      ],
      "targets": {
        "SalesList": {
          "type": "Component",
          "id": "SalesList",
          "name": "sap.fe.templates.ListReport",
          "options": {
            "settings": {
              "entitySet": "SalesOrders",
              "navigation": {
                "SalesOrders": {
                  "detail": {
                    "route": "SalesDetails"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "SalesDetails": {
          "type": "Component",
          "id": "SalesDetails",
          "name": "sap.fe.templates.ObjectPage",
          "options": {
            "settings": {
              "entitySet": "SalesOrders"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
      "compact": true,
      "cozy": true
    }
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "fullWidth": false
  },
  "sap.fiori": {
    "registrationIds": [],
    "archeType": "transactional"
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Below is the metadata document for the service I used to generate the application.

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://oasis-tcs.github.io/odata-vocabularies/vocabularies/Org.OData.Capabilities.V1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Capabilities.V1" Alias="Capabilities"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap.github.io/odata-vocabularies/vocabularies/Common.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1" Alias="Common"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://oasis-tcs.github.io/odata-vocabularies/vocabularies/Org.OData.Core.V1.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="Org.OData.Core.V1" Alias="Core"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:Reference Uri="https://sap.github.io/odata-vocabularies/vocabularies/UI.xml">
        <edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1" Alias="UI"/>
    </edmx:Reference>
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="project">
            <EntityType Name="Currencies">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="code"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="name" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
                <Property Name="descr" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="1000"/>
                <Property Name="code" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="3"/>
                <Property Name="symbol" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="texts" Type="Collection(project.Currencies_texts)">
                    <OnDelete Action="Cascade"/>
                </NavigationProperty>
                <NavigationProperty Name="localized" Type="project.Currencies_texts">
                    <ReferentialConstraint Property="code" ReferencedProperty="code"/>
                </NavigationProperty>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Currencies_texts">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="locale"/>
                    <PropertyRef Name="code"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="locale" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="14"/>
                <Property Name="name" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
                <Property Name="descr" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="1000"/>
                <Property Name="code" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="3"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="POrders">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false"/>
                <Property Name="createdAt" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
                <Property Name="createdBy" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
                <Property Name="modifiedAt" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7"/>
                <Property Name="modifiedBy" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255"/>
                <Property Name="OrderNo" Type="Edm.String"/>
                <Property Name="total" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="9" Scale="2"/>
                <Property Name="currency_code" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="currency" Type="project.Currencies">
                    <ReferentialConstraint Property="currency_code" ReferencedProperty="code"/>
                </NavigationProperty>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="PurchaseOrderItems">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="EBELN"/>
                    <PropertyRef Name="EBELP"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="EBELN" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10"/>
                <Property Name="EBELP" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="5"/>
                <Property Name="MATNR" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40"/>
                <Property Name="WERKS" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="PurchaseOrders">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="EBELN"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="EBELN" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10"/>
                <Property Name="BUKRS" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4"/>
                <Property Name="BEDAT" Type="Edm.Date"/>
                <Property Name="STATU" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="1"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="Items" Type="Collection(project.PurchaseOrderItems)">
                    <OnDelete Action="Cascade"/>
                </NavigationProperty>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="SalesOrderItems">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="POSNR"/>
                    <PropertyRef Name="VBELN"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="POSNR" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="6"/>
                <Property Name="VBELN" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10"/>
                <Property Name="MATNR" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40"/>
                <Property Name="MEINS" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3"/>
                <Property Name="ZMENG" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20"/>
                <Property Name="NETPR" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20"/>
                <Property Name="WAERK" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5"/>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="SalesOrders">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="VBELN"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="VBELN" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10"/>
                <Property Name="AUDAT" Type="Edm.Date"/>
                <Property Name="AUART" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4"/>
                <Property Name="KUNNR" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="10"/>
                <NavigationProperty Name="Items" Type="Collection(project.SalesOrderItems)">
                    <OnDelete Action="Cascade"/>
                </NavigationProperty>
            </EntityType>
            <EntityContainer Name="EntityContainer">
                <EntitySet Name="Currencies" EntityType="project.Currencies">
                    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="texts" Target="Currencies_texts"/>
                    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="localized" Target="Currencies_texts"/>
                </EntitySet>
                <EntitySet Name="Currencies_texts" EntityType="project.Currencies_texts"/>
                <EntitySet Name="POrders" EntityType="project.POrders">
                    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="currency" Target="Currencies"/>
                </EntitySet>
                <EntitySet Name="PurchaseOrderItems" EntityType="project.PurchaseOrderItems"/>
                <EntitySet Name="PurchaseOrders" EntityType="project.PurchaseOrders">
                    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Items" Target="PurchaseOrderItems"/>
                </EntitySet>
                <EntitySet Name="SalesOrderItems" EntityType="project.SalesOrderItems"/>
                <EntitySet Name="SalesOrders" EntityType="project.SalesOrders">
                    <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Items" Target="SalesOrderItems"/>
                </EntitySet>
            </EntityContainer>
            <Annotations Target="project.Currencies">
                <Annotation Term="UI.Identification">
                    <Collection>
                        <Record Type="UI.DataField">
                            <PropertyValue Property="Value">
                                <Path>name</Path>
                            </PropertyValue>
                        </Record>
                    </Collection>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.Currencies/name">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Name</String>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.Currencies/descr">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Description</String>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.Currencies/code">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Currency Code</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Common.Text">
                    <Path>name</Path>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.Currencies/symbol">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Currency Symbol</String>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.Currencies_texts/name">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Name</String>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.Currencies_texts/descr">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Description</String>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.Currencies_texts/code">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Currency Code</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Common.Text">
                    <Path>name</Path>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/ID">
                <Annotation Term="Core.Computed">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/createdAt">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Created On</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Computed">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Immutable">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="UI.HiddenFilter">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/createdBy">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Created By</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Computed">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Description">
                    <String>User's unique ID</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Immutable">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="UI.HiddenFilter">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/modifiedAt">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Changed On</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Computed">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="UI.HiddenFilter">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/modifiedBy">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Changed By</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Computed">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Description">
                    <String>User's unique ID</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="UI.HiddenFilter">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/OrderNo">
                <Annotation Term="Common.FieldControl">
                    <EnumMember>Common.FieldControlType/Mandatory</EnumMember>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Order Number</String>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/total">
                <Annotation Term="Core.Computed">
                    <Bool>true</Bool>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/currency">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Currency</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Description">
                    <String>Currency code as specified by ISO 4217</String>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.POrders/currency_code">
                <Annotation Term="Common.Label">
                    <String>Currency</String>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListType">
                        <PropertyValue Property="Label">
                            <String>Currency</String>
                        </PropertyValue>
                        <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath">
                            <String>Currencies</String>
                        </PropertyValue>
                        <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                            <Collection>
                                <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterInOut">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty">
                                        <PropertyPath>currency_code</PropertyPath>
                                    </PropertyValue>
                                    <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty">
                                        <String>code</String>
                                    </PropertyValue>
                                </Record>
                                <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                                    <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty">
                                        <String>name</String>
                                    </PropertyValue>
                                </Record>
                            </Collection>
                        </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Core.Description">
                    <String>Currency code as specified by ISO 4217</String>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
            <Annotations Target="project.EntityContainer/SalesOrders">
                <Annotation Term="Capabilities.DeleteRestrictions">
                    <Record Type="Capabilities.DeleteRestrictionsType">
                        <PropertyValue Property="Deletable">
                            <Bool>false</Bool>
                        </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Capabilities.InsertRestrictions">
                    <Record Type="Capabilities.InsertRestrictionsType">
                        <PropertyValue Property="Insertable">
                            <Bool>false</Bool>
                        </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>
                </Annotation>
                <Annotation Term="Capabilities.UpdateRestrictions">
                    <Record Type="Capabilities.UpdateRestrictionsType">
                        <PropertyValue Property="Updatable">
                            <Bool>false</Bool>
                        </PropertyValue>
                    </Record>
                </Annotation>
            </Annotations>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Do you have any annotations to go with this service? I'm assuming there are some since there's columns displayed

Comment: Yes, I have the annotations. I'll add them to the post.